# Button OnClick not navigating to another screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm trying to add an OnClick for a button, that navigates to another screen, however, it isn't working. My code is the same side by side with similar code, that is working (for another set of screens), but this one doesn't. I'm trying to get the "reset" button to trigger navigation to CounterEditScreen.

Navigation.kt:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@Composable
fun Navigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Routes.TASKSLIST.route) {
        composable(
            Routes.TASKSLIST.route
        ) {
            TasksListScreen(onNavigate = {
                navController.navigate(it.route)
            })
        }
        composable(
            route = Routes.ADDEDITTASK.route + "?taskId={taskId}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(name = "taskId") {
                type = NavType.IntType
                defaultValue = -1
            })
        ) {
            AddEditScreen(
                onPopBackStack = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                })
        }
        composable(
            Routes.COUNTER.route
        ) {
            CounterScreen(onNavigate = {
                navController.navigate(it.route)
            })
        }
        composable(
            route = Routes.COUNTEREDIT.route
        ) {
            CounterEditScreen(
                onPopBackStack = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

CounterViewModel:

```
class CounterViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiEvent = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val uiEvent = _uiEvent.receiveAsFlow()

    fun onEvent(event: CounterEvent) {
        when (event) {
            CounterEvent.OnButtonSwitch -> TODO()
            is CounterEvent.OnCounterNameChange -> TODO()
            is CounterEvent.OnCounterReset -> {
                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(Routes.COUNTEREDIT.route))
                }
            }
            is CounterEvent.OnDrawerNavigationClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(event.navigationItem.route))
            }
        }
    }


    private fun sendUiEvent(event: UiEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _uiEvent.send(event)
        }
    }
}
```

CounterEvent:

```
sealed class CounterEvent {
    object OnCounterNameChange : CounterEvent()
    data class OnDrawerNavigationClick(val navigationItem: NavigationItem) : CounterEvent()
    object OnCounterReset : CounterEvent()
    object OnButtonSwitch : CounterEvent()
}
```

Counter.kt:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CounterScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onNavigate: (UiEvent.Navigate) -> Unit,
) {
    val viewModel = CounterViewModel()
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    var selectedItemIndex by rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    val days by rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    val counterName by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("Cold showers")
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.uiEvent.collectLatest { event ->
            when (event) {
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                    onNavigate(event)
                }
                else -> Unit
            }
        }
    }
    ModalNavigationDrawer(drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
                NavigationDrawerItem(
                    label = { Text(item.title) },
                    selected = index == selectedItemIndex,
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.onEvent(CounterEvent.OnDrawerNavigationClick(item))
                        selectedItemIndex = index
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            drawerState.close()
                        }
                    },
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = if (index == selectedItemIndex) {
                                item.selectedIcon
                            } else item.unselectedIcon, contentDescription = item.title
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                )
            }
        }
    }, drawerState = drawerState) {
        Scaffold(
            snackbarHost = {
                SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) { data ->
                    Snackbar(
                        shape = RoundedShapes.medium,
                        actionColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                        snackbarData = data
                    )
                }
            },
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = { Text("Day counter") },
                    colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                    ),
                    navigationIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            coroutineScope.launch { drawerState.open() }
                        }) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu,
                                contentDescription = "Menu"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            },
        ) { padding ->
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(padding)
                    .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
                Text(
                    text = "$counterName\ndays passed: $days",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                    modifier = modifier.clickable {
                        viewModel.onEvent(CounterEvent.OnCounterNameChange)
                    },
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
                Button(
                    onClick = { viewModel.onEvent(CounterEvent.OnButtonSwitch) },
                    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Start")
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
                Button(
                    onClick = { viewModel.onEvent(CounterEvent.OnCounterReset) },
                    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Reset")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the way you get the `CounterViewModel` in the `CounterScreen`.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

fun CounterScreen(
    onNavigate: (UiEvent.Navigate) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel : CounterViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
//    val viewModel = CounterViewModel()
```

You might have to add `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1` dependency.

My theory: with this `val viewModel = CounterViewModel()` code a new instance of the `CounterViewModel` will be created on each `CounterScreen` recomposition. Because of that a `CounterViewModel` instance that being collected from in the `LaunchedEffect` and an instance used in the "Reset" button's `onClick` most likely will be different. With `viewModels()` function you will get the same instance of the `CounterViewModel` on every recomposition.

Comment: Perfect answer doesn't exi-
Thanks a lot, perfectly explained!